# Chaining Class Constructors at the end

Tags: c#

I have some old code from someone else that I need to fix so it builds again and one issue that I don't know how to fix, is constructor chaining. It looks something like this:

```
class Foo(){

  public Foo()
  {
    int i = /*block of code*/;
    this (i);
  }

  public Foo(int i)
  {
    //..
  }
}
```

The error comes at the `this (i);` line where it says `Method, delegate, or event is expected`. Basically it no longer allows you to use `this` as just a constructor anymore. Maybe it did in older version of C#.

What would be the appropriate way to fix this? I can replace `public Foo()` with `public Foo(): this(i)` but then it doesn't recognize the variable `i` anymore.

Comment: _"Basically it no longer allows you to use this as just a constructor anymore. Maybe it did in older version of C#."_ - **nope**, that has _never_ been a feature of C# (though I want it so badly).

Comment: _"What would be the appropriate way to fix this?"_ - you can't, at least, not like that, because the C# language does not let you run arbitrary code to mutate _instance state_ prior to calling the supertype's constructor. The CLR _does_ let you (as C# `record` types **do** have a reversed init order, in-fact) but C# does not currently expose this to users, which is super annoying.

Comment: The workaround is to have a static method that does the computation for `i`, then use `public Foo() : this(ComputeValue()) { ... }`

Comment: The only way the code could genuinely look like that is if it's the product of a decompiler that's using pseudo-syntax to represent something that's there on the IL level but not directly expressible in the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a block of code before calling `this()`, you can use a static method:

```
class Foo()
{
    public Foo() : this(SomeMethod())
    {
    }

    public Foo(int i)
    {
        //..
    }

    private static int SomeMethod()
    {
        int i = /*block of code*/;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Note that you can't mutate the instance state in `SomeMethod()`, but such logic should probably be in `Foo(int i)` anyway.